# counting letters (only letters) in a long string (python 2.72)

Tags: string, count, letters

i need to write a function which receives a long string, and puts into a dictionary
each letter, and it's it's appearance frequency in the string.
iv'e written the next function, but the problem it doesn't ignore whitespaces, numbers etc..
iv'e been asked to use the function `symbol in string.ascii_lowercase`, but iv'e no idea how to do it. 
this is my code:

```
def calc_freq(txt):
   dic={}
   for letter in range(len(txt)):
           if dic.has_key(txt[letter])==True:
                dic[txt[letter]] += 1
           else:
            dic[txt[letter]] = 1
   return dic
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

s = 'oasndoasndoansdakls'
count = []
dictionary = {}

for x in set(s):
     if x in string.ascii_lowercase:
          dictionary[x] = s.count(x)

print (dictionary)
```

this will create a dictionary of the charactors and their counts, and only include them if they are in the `string.ascii_lowercase` list.

---

Here is how to use it in your code:

```
import string

def calc_freq(txt):
     dic={}
     for letter in txt:
          if letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
               if letter in dic:
                    dic[letter] += 1
               else:
                    dic[letter] = 1
     return dic
```

you just needed to add an if statment before you add the letter to the dictionary or increase its count.

I also removed the `letter in range(txt)` and `txt[letter]`, you can access each charactor directly in python, because a string is an `iterable` and can be treated similar to a list.

Comment: @Orr added, I made it a bit easier to read for you, but if you want your original code, just replace what I changed.

Comment: what is the error? what are you passing it? It's working perfetly in my test, can I please have an example of input?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#133>", line 1, in <module>
    calc_freq('zoobi')
  File "<pyshell#132>", line 4, in calc_freq
    if letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
NameError: global name 'string' is not defined

Comment: you need to add `import string` to the top of your python file to access the lower_case list.

Answer (score 0):

just for fun:

```
s = 'Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.'
print dict(filter(lambda i: str.isalnum(i[0]), set(zip(a,map(a.count,a)))))
```

> {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'e': 6, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'f': 2, 'i': 5, 'h': 2, 'm':
>   2, 'l': 2, 'o': 6, 'n': 3, 'p': 3, 's': 2, 'r': 6, 't': 3, 'y': 2,
>   'T': 1}